# DataTables (AJAX+PHP), Search, Sorting e Pagination não funcionam (Congelamento da tabela)

Tags: php, ajax, datatable

O DataTables está funcionando, todos os Buttons funcionam e chamam a tabela, estou utilizando load para abrir a tabela por ajax, faz o reload normalmente, porém as demais ações não, como:

- Paginação, clica na página 2, muda as descrições abaixo e o número da página, mas não muda as linhas;
- Buscar, não funciona, porém utilizando uma busca externa com myFunction de uma coluna, funciona;
- Ordenar, não funciona, o ícone até muda para baixo ou para cima...

O que estou entendendo que os valores puxados pelo Ajax da lista gerado pelo PHP estão estáticas e nada muda.

Quando utilizava o foreach dentro da página e listava tudo, funciona corretamente... Estava querendo separar para poder trabalhar com reload e colocar inserir e editar com modais sem precisar atualizar a página.

equipAll.php

```html
<?php

include '../datasourceGestao.php';

$datasource = new datasource();

$result = $datasource->getAllEquip();

$row = array(); 

foreach ($result as $array) {
    $row[] = array('admin_id' => $array['admin_id'],
     'first_name' => $array['first_name'],
     'last_name' => $array['last_name'],
     'email' => $array['email'],
     'gender' => $array['gender'],
     'birth_date' => $datasource->invertDate($array['birth_date']),
     'telephone' => $array['telephone'],
     'mobile' => $array['mobile'],
     'nivel' => $array['nivel'],
     'status' => $array['status']
    );
}

$output = array(
 "draw"       =>  intval($_POST["draw"]),
 "iTotalRecords" => count($row),
 "iTotalDisplayRecords" => count($row),
 "aaData" => $row
);

$response = json_encode($output);
echo $response;

?>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  var table = $('#myTable').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip', 
        processing:true,
        serverSide:true,
        ajax:{
          "url": "php_action/equipAll.php",
          "type":"POST"
        },
        autoWidth: false,
        responsive: true,
        orderCellsTop: true,
        bFilter: true,
        fixedHeader: false,
        deferRender: true,
        pagingType: "full_numbers", 
        lengthMenu: [
            [ 10, 25, 50, -1 ],
            [ '10 linhas', '25 linhas', '50 linhas', 'Todos' ]
        ],
        searching: true,
        select: true,        
        select: {
            style: 'multi+shift',
        },    
        columns: [
          { data: 'admin_id' },
          { data: 'action' },
          { data: 'first_name'},
          { data: 'last_name' },
          { data: 'email' },
          { data: 'gender',
              "defaultContent": "",
              "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                if("1"==sData){
                  $(nTd).html("<i class='fas fa-venus ze-icon-m'></i>");
                } 
                else if("2"==sData){
                  $(nTd).html("<i class='fas fa-mars ze-icon-m'></i>");
                }                  
                else{
                  $(nTd).html("<i class='fas fa-venus-mars ze-icon-m'></i>");
                }  
              }
            },
            { data: 'birth_date' },
            { data: 'telephone' },
            { data: 'mobile' },
            { data: 'nivel',
                "defaultContent": "",
                "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                  if("1"==sData){
                    $(nTd).html("<i class='fas fa-user-tie ze-icon-m'></i>");
                  }  
                  else{
                    $(nTd).html("<i class='fas fa-user ze-icon-m'></i>");
                  }  
                }
            },
            { data: 'status',
                "defaultContent": "",
                "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                  if("2"==sData){
                    $(nTd).html("<i class='fas fa-toggle-on ze-icon-m'></i>");
                  }  
                  else{
                    $(nTd).html("<i class='fas fa-toggle-off ze-icon-m'></i>");
                  }  
                }  
            }            
        ],
        columnDefs: [
            {
                "targets": [ 0 ],
                "visible": true,
                "searchable": true,
                "data": "admin_id"
            },
            {
                "targets": [ 1 ],
                "data": null,
                "defaultContent": "<div class='btn-group' role='group' aria-label='Button group with nested dropdown'><div class='btn-group' role='group'><button id='btnGroupDrop1' type='button' class='btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'><i class='fas fa-cogs ze-icon-m' aria-hidden='true'></i></button><div class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='btnGroupDrop1'><button type='button' class='btn btn-link' id='Detail' name='Detail'><i class='fas fa-eye ze-icon-m' aria-hidden='true'></i></button><button type='button' class='btn btn-link' id='Edit' name='Edit'><i class='fas fa-edit ze-icon-m'></i></button><button type='button' class='btn btn-link' id='confirmDelete' name='confirmDelete'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt ze-icon-m'></i></button><button type='submit' class='btn btn-link' id ='confirmStatus' name='confirmStatus'><i class='fas fa-toggle-on ze-icon-m'></i></button></div></div></div> "
            },            
            {
                "targets": [ 2 ],
                "visible": true,
                "searchable": true,
                "data": "first_name"
            },
            {
                "targets": [ 3 ],
                "visible": true,
                "searchable": true,
                "data": "last_name"
            },
            {
                "targets": [ 4 ],
                "visible": true,
                "searchable": true,
                "data": "email"
            },
            {
                "targets": [ 5 ],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": true,
                "data": "gender",
            },
            {
                "targets": [ 6 ],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": true,
                "data": "birth_date"
            },
            {
                "targets": [ 7 ],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": true,
                "data": "telephone"
            },
            {
                "targets": [ 8 ],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": true,
                "data": "mobile"
            },
            {
                "targets": [ 9 ],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": true,
                "data": "nivel"
            },
            {
                "targets": [ 10 ],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false,
                "data": "status"
            }    
        ],
        buttons: [
            {
              extend:    '',
              text:      '<i class="fa fa-user-plus ze-icon-gg" style="color:blue;"></i>',
              titleAttr: 'Novo Registro',
              action: function (e, node, config){
                $('#myModalInsert').modal('show')
              }
            },
            {
              extend:    'pageLength',
              text:      '<i class="fas fa-list-ol ze-icon-gg" style="color:purple;"></i>',
              titleAttr: 'Mostrar',                   
            },   
            {
              extend:    'copyHtml5',
              text:      '<i class="fas fa-copy ze-icon-gg" style="color:gray;"></i>',
              titleAttr: 'Copiar',       
              key: {
                key: 'c',
                altKey: true
              },
              exportOptions: {
                modifier: {
                  page: 'current',
                  columns: ':visible'              
                }
              }  
            },
            {
             extend:    'excelHtml5',
              text:      '<i class="fas fa-file-excel ze-icon-gg" style="color:green;"></i>',
              titleAttr: 'Excel',
              exportOptions: {
               modifier: {
                 page: 'current',
                  columns: ':visible'              
               }
             }             
            },            
            {
              extend:    'pdfHtml5',
              text:      '<i class="far fa-file-pdf ze-icon-gg" style="color:red; background-color:transparent;"></i>',
              titleAttr: 'PDF',
              orientation: 'A4', //portrait or landscape
              alignment: 'center',     
              pageSize:  'LEGAL',
              exportOptions: {
                  columns: ':visible'                 
              }        
            },
            {
              extend:    'print',
              text:      '<i class="fas fa-print ze-icon-gg" style="color:orange;"></i>',
              titleAttr: 'Print',
              exportOptions: {
                columns: ':visible'              
              }          
            },
            {
              extend:    'colvis',
              text:      '<i class="fas fa-columns ze-icon-gg"></i>',
              titleAttr: 'Alterar Colunas Visiveis',
              "columns": ':not(.noVis)'         
           },
            {
              extend:    'selectNone',
              text:      '<i class="fas fa-th ze-icon-gg"></i>',
              titleAttr: 'Remover todos os selecionados'
            },
            {
              extend:    'selectRows' ,
              text:      '<i class="fas fa-minus ze-icon-gg"></i>',
              titleAttr: 'Selecionar linha(s)'
            },           {
              extend:    'selectColumns',
              text:      '<i class="fas fa-th-large ze-icon-gg"></i>',
              titleAttr: 'Selecionar coluna(s)'
            },
            {
              extend:    'selectCells',
              text:      '<i class="fas fa-object-group ze-icon-gg"></i>',
              titleAttr: 'Selecionar celula(s)'
            }                                           
        ],
        language: {
          "decimal":        "",
          "emptyTable":     "Não avaliação deste registro",
          "info":           "Mostrar de _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
          "infoEmpty":      "Mostrar 0 de 0 de 0 registros",
          "infoFiltered":   "(Total de _MAX_ registros de entradas)",
          "infoPostFix":    "",
          "thousands":      ",",
          "lengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
          "loadingRecords": "Carregando...",
          "processing":     "Processando...",
          "search":         "Buscar:",
          "zeroRecords":    "Não há registros",
          "paginate": {
              "first":      "<<",
              "last":       ">>",
              "next":       ">",
              "previous":   "<" 
          },
          "loadingRecords": '&nbsp;',
          "processing": 'Processando...',        
          "aria": {
            "sortAscending":  ": Coluna ativa em ordem ascendente",
            "sortDescending": ": Coluna ativa em ordem descendente"
          },
          "select": {
              "rows": {
                "_": "(Selecionado %d linhas)",
                "0": "(Nenhuma linha selecionada)",
                "1": "(Selecionado 1 linha)"
              },
              "columns": {
                "_": "(Selecionado %d colunas)",
                "0": "(Nenhuma coluna selecionada)",
                "1": "(Selecionado 1 coluna)"
              }
          },
          "buttons": {
              "copy": "Copiar para a área de transferência",
              "copyTitle": "Cópia bem sucedida",
              "copySuccess": {
                  "1": "Uma linha copiada com sucesso",
                  "_": "%d linhas copiadas com sucesso"
              }
          }                      
        }

  });
```

```html
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-hover display nowrap dataTable" cellspacing="0">
   <thead class="thead-dark">
    <th class="ze-center" data-priority="1">ID</th>
    <th class="ze-center" data-priority="1">Opções</th>
    <th class="w-50" data-priority="1">Nome</th>
    <th class="w-50" data-priority="1">Sobrenome</th>
    <th class="ze-center">E-mail</th>
    <th class="ze-center">Gênero</th>
    <th class="ze-center">Dt Nasc.</th>
    <th class="ze-center">Telefone</th>
    <th class="ze-center">Mobile</th>
    <th class="ze-center">Nivel</th>
    <th class="ze-center">Status</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>

<?php
    if (count($result) == 0) {
?>
      <td colspan="4">Não há Membros Cadastrados</td>
<?php
    }
    else {    

 foreach ($result as $array) {
?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo utf8_encode($array['admin_id']); ?></td>
     <td>
     </td>
   <td class="ze-left">
      <?php echo utf8_encode($array['first_name']); ?>
   </td>
    <td><?php echo utf8_encode($array['last_name']); ?></td>   
    <td><?php echo utf8_encode($array['email']); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo ($array['gender'] == 1 ? "Masculino" : "Feminino"); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo utf8_encode($array['birth_date']); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo utf8_encode($array['telephone']); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo utf8_encode($array['mobile']); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo utf8_encode($array['nivel']); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo utf8_encode($array['status']); ?></td>
 </tr>
  <?php }
  } ?>
 </tbody>
   <tfoot class="thead-dark">
    <th class="ze-center">ID</th>
    <th class="ze-center">Opções</th>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>Sobrenome</th>
    <th class="ze-center">E-mail</th>
    <th class="ze-center">Gênero</th>
    <th class="ze-center">Dt Nasc.</th>
    <th class="ze-center">Telefone</th>
    <th class="ze-center">Mobile</th>
    <th class="ze-center">Nivel</th>
    <th class="ze-center">Status</th>
   </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

A página precisa ser trabalhada no PHP, para que filtre, busque e ordene...

Segue o código feito e funcionando:

```
    <?php

include '../datasourceGestao.php';

$datasource = new datasource();

## Recebendo os $_POST

$draw = $_POST['draw'];

$row = $_POST['start'];

$row_per_page = $_POST['length']; // Linha por página

$column_index = $_POST['order'][0]['column']; // Column index

$column_name = $_POST['columns'][$column_index]['data']; // Column name

if($column_name=="admin_id" or $column_name=="action"){ $column_name = "first_name"; }

$column_sort_order = $_POST['order'][0]['dir']; // asc or desc

$search_value = $_POST['search']['value']; // Search value

## Resultados

if(!empty($column_index)){ $order = $column_name ." " . $column_sort_order . " "; }
else{ $order = "first_name ASC "; }

if($row_per_page != -1){ $pages = $row . ", " . $row_per_page; }
else{ $pages = "1, 10";  }

if(!empty($search_value)){

    $result = $datasource->getAllEquipSearch($search_value,$order,$pages);
}
else{

    $result = $datasource->getAllEquip($order,$pages);
}

$data = array();    

foreach ($result[0] as $array) {
    $data[] = array('admin_id' => $array['admin_id'],
        'first_name' => $array['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $array['last_name'],
        'email' => $array['email'],
        'gender' => $array['gender'],
        'birth_date' => $datasource->invertDate($array['birth_date']),
        'telephone' => $array['telephone'],
        'mobile' => $array['mobile'],
        'nivel' => $array['nivel'],
        'status' => $array['status']
    );
}

$output = array(
    "draw"       =>  intval($_POST["draw"]),
    "iTotalRecords" => $result[1],
    "iTotalDisplayRecords" => count($result[0]), // Total de Filtrados
    "aaData" => $data
);

echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

Como utilizo o datasource.php para os envios, segue:

```
public function getAllEquip($order,$pages) {
        try {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT admin_id, first_name, last_name, email,
                                            gender, birth_date, telephone, mobile, nivel, status  
                                            FROM tbl_admins
                                            ORDER BY $order
                                            LIMIT $pages");
            $stmt->execute();

            $stmt2 = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT admin_id, first_name, last_name, email,
                                            gender, birth_date, telephone, mobile, nivel, status  
                                            FROM tbl_admins");
            $stmt2->execute();

            if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                $result = array (
                    $stmt->fetchAll(),
                    $stmt2->rowCount(),
                );
                return $result;         
            }
        }
        catch(PDOExeption $e) {
            http_response_code(500);
            sql_error("MYSQL ERROR: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>");
        }
    }

    public function getAllEquipSearch($search_value,$order,$pages) {
        try {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT admin_id, first_name, last_name, email,
                                            gender, birth_date, telephone, mobile, nivel, status  
                                            FROM tbl_admins
                                            WHERE first_name LIKE '%$search_value%' 
                                            OR last_name LIKE '%$search_value%' 
                                            OR email LIKE '%$search_value%' 
                                            OR telephone LIKE '%$search_value%' 
                                            OR mobile LIKE '%$search_value%'
                                            ORDER BY $order
                                            LIMIT $pages");
            $stmt->execute();

            $stmt2 = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT admin_id, first_name, last_name, email,
                                            gender, birth_date, telephone, mobile, nivel, status  
                                            FROM tbl_admins
                                            WHERE first_name LIKE '%$search_value%' 
                                            OR last_name LIKE '%$search_value%' 
                                            OR email LIKE '%$search_value%' 
                                            OR telephone LIKE '%$search_value%' 
                                            OR mobile LIKE '%$search_value%'");
            $stmt2->execute();

            if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                $result = array (
                    $stmt->fetchAll(),
                    $stmt2->rowCount(),
                );
                return $result;
            }
          }
        catch(PDOExeption $e) {
            http_response_code(500);
            sql_error("MYSQL ERROR: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Só estou tentando descobrir porque não abri a segunda página em diante de registros...